# Помогите решить две простых задачи в SQL. Не уверен в первом ответе, а во втором тем более :С

Tags: sql

3.2 Даны две таблицы: `cars [ id, name, color, f_id ]` и `factory [ id, name ]`.

3.2.1. Написать запрос, который из таблицы `cars` выведет наименования всех машин красного цвета:

Ответ: `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE color = "red"`

3.2.2. Написать запрос, который из таблицы `cars` выведет наименования всех машин черного цвета, которые сделаны на заводе “FORD” (известно, что поле `f_id` в таблице `cars` является внешним ключом  к полю `id` таблицы `factory`):

Ответ  `SELECT  * FROM cars WHERE color = 'black' and name= “FORD”`

Comment: Вас просят вывести только наименования, так что `*` это слишком много. Во втором запросе вам намекают, что таблица factory должна быть использована. И это так потому что name именно из нее должен быть FORD. (А сейчас у вас название машины а не завода такое) Вам надо применить join или IN с подзапросом

Comment: Хорошо бы указать, какую именно СУБД используете: SqlServer, MySql, Oracle и т. п. Потому что некоторые детали в них различаются.

Comment: Ну вы попробовали выполнить эти запросы? Какой результат получили?

Comment: В одиночных кавычках записываются литералы. В двойных - имена колонок.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вывести нужно только наименование (`name`), а не все столбцы

   ```
   SELECT name FROM cars WHERE color = 'red';
   ```
2. Производитель - это `factory`, отсев должен быть по `factory.name`, а не `cars.name`. 
   Вывести нужно только наименование (`cars.name`), а не все столбцы. 
   Так как в обеих таблицах есть одноименные поля, необходимо использовать псевдонимы таблиц

   ```
   SELECT c.name
   FROM cars AS c
   JOIN factory AS f ON f.id = c.f_id
   WHERE c.color = 'black'
     AND f.name = 'FORD';`
   ```

Comment: Добавьте пояснения, что было неправильно у автора и что вы изменили.